# Customizable calender control for attendance module

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, calendar

I am building website in .net by using MVC4 in Visual Studio 2012. I have got a problem while working in the attendance module. I want a customizable calender for attendance so that I can mark absent and present. Can someone tell me any calender control in jQuery or in JavaScript so that I can proceed further.

Answer (score 0):

you could try using [fullcalendar](http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/) using the agendaDay or basicDay view formats.

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend you to try [.NET Scheduler](http://scheduler-net.com/)  or the javascript scheduler [http://docs.dhtmlx.com/doku.php?id=dhtmlxscheduler:toc](http://docs.dhtmlx.com/doku.php?id=dhtmlxscheduler%3atoc)